# Testing Backbone Events set up in the initialize function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, jasmine

I'm trying to set up my collection to listen to events triggered on models within the collection, like so:

```
var Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this.on('playback:completed', this.playNext);
  },
  playNext : function() { }
});
```

In my tests, I add new Backbone.Models into an instance of the collection, and then trigger `playback:completed` on them... and `playNext` isn't called. How do I set this up correctly?

EDIT: adding test code (uses Jasmine):

```
var collection;

describe('Collection', function() {

  beforeEach(function() { 
    collection = new Collection();
  });

  it('should playNext when playback:completed is triggered', function() {
    var model1 = new Backbone.Model();
    var model2 = new Backbone.Model();
    var spy = spyOn(collection, 'playNext').andCallThrough();
    collection.add(model1);
    collection.add(model2);
    model1.trigger('playback:completed');
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Comment: It should work: http://jsfiddle.net/KfmG5/. The problem comes from something else. Post more code maybe.

Comment: Very weird--there's not really more code. The only complication I left out is it's a Jasmine test and there is a spy on playNext.

Comment: Maybe add the part where you trigger the event.

Comment: Strangely, this works if I write the event listener outside of the initialize function (e.g. `collection.on('playback:completed', collection.playNext);` in the body of the test. Is something wrong with the initialize function?

Comment: Shouldn't be any. The only thing that could be wrong would be the context. But I don't know how the context could not be the object itself in the initialize function (a problem with Jasmine maybe?).

Comment: I'm guessing based on http://stackoverflow.com/a/8869520/221814 that the problem is the way Backbone calls the function in this case--but the suggested solution there (for views) doesn't work here (`bind` is never called either).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that backbone's `.on` wraps the callback as a clone or something like it. Since the spy is set up after Collection.initialize runs, the callback that's been wrapped is the function before setting the spy, it's never triggered.

The solution I settled on was to pull the event bindings into a `bindEvents` function, like so:

```
var Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
  },
  bindEvents : function() {
    this.on('playback:completed', this.playNext);
  },
  playNext : function() { }
});
```

Then, in my test (and after the spy is set), I ran `collection.off(); collection.bindEvents();`, which re-binds them with the spied versions.